# How to make a arrayclass access with this[][]

Tags: c#, arrays, class, matrix, this

I want to create an Matrix class for some calculations. At my research i was stumble over some performance discussions `Array[,]` vs `Array[][]` and they conclusion was always use `Array[][]` if you want it fast

When i'm trying to provide access to an value via `[][]` it seems like i miss something important because i cant create an property like this

```
    public double this[int iRow][int iCol]   
    {
        get { return matrix[iRow][iCol]; }
        set { matrix[iRow][iCol] = value; }
    }
```

my problem is the second [] because the following works well

```
    public double this[int iRow,int iCol]   
    {
        get { return matrix[iRow][iCol]; }
        set { matrix[iRow][iCol] = value; }
    }
```

**So what do i need to add in this class to let it work with [][] ?**

```
public class Matrix
{
    private bool _isSquare;

    private double[][] matrix;

    public double this[int iRow,int iCol]   
    {
        get { return matrix[iRow][iCol]; }
        set { matrix[iRow][iCol] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: why not make your matrix `get;private set;`?

Comment: @Sayse how does this solve my problem? and at the moment the accessibility doesn't matter

Comment: I've added an answer to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in one class.

```
var b = a[1][2];
```

is the same as

```
var temp = a[1];
var b = temp[2];
```

They are two separate indexing operations.

Your first indexer would need to return an instance of some class that also has an indexer.

- [Using Indexers (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2549tw02.aspx)

Comment: mhh so i will never be able to get the selected `col` if i' want access the value via `myMatrix[row][col]` right? because i can only return an `double[]` which will get the `col`

Comment: You're correct. What's wrong with using the 2D indexer like you have shown at the bottom? (`this[int iRow,int iCol]`)

Comment: if i use intern `[][]` but provide access via `[,]` some people would maybe think is also use intern the slower `[,]` so thought i would be nice to reflect the array type which i intern use

Comment: I'm assuming by "intern" you mean "internally". It's very important to be very clear and not lazy with terminology (as [interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) is something else altogether.)

Comment: But no, what you're saying goes against the whole point of abstract data types. The internals are just that: *internal*. They are hidden from the consumer of the class, and you are free to implement and modify the internals however you wish, as long as the outside interface remains the same.  Personally, I think `[x,y]` makes more sense anyway.

Comment: that wasn't laziness it's just bad english knowledge ;) so you are right i'm mean internally

Comment: Fair enough. But regardless your options are limited here. Either use the 2D indexer, or expose the internal `[][]` array via a property/field.

Comment: mhh maybe you are right but Sayse suggestion looks also interesting so i will check both and will see which on will feel more natural

Comment: Right, that's what I meant by "expose..." - Sayse's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do but if your matrix was the following you could still do what you are looking for

```
public class M
{
    public double[][] Matrix { get; private set; }
    public M()
    {
        Matrix = new double[2][]{new double[2], new double[2]};
    }
}

M n = new M();
n.Matrix[0][0] = 1.0;
```

Comment: Why even use a `class` then? This is just an array-of-array-of-double. The whole array can be modified, you just can't assign a new one.

Comment: It looked to me like he wanted a short hand way of writing a value to a matrix, nothign stopping this class being expanded to include mathematics